# why do I keep getting 403 and 404 errors in the MIDDLE of downloads using DownThemAll? Very frustrating

Tags: firefox, download-manager, http-status-code-404

looking up 404 error code, I find that it's supposed to only occur when a file or http source is no longer available at the specified location. but I'm getting it in the middle of downloads! makes no sense. and it happens to 1 out of every 4 or 5 downloads. especially if they're larger than 100MB.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on where the downloads are coming from, the link you're using may be expiring.

If I recall correctly, download managers like DownLoadThemAll will use multiple connections to download different parts of a given file. Many download sites use a system where when a user opens the download page they are given a randomly generated download link which points to the real file (i.e. http://www.example.com/download.php?file=randomstring, though it could appear to be anything). This random link will expire after a short period of time so that anyone trying to use it will get an error. They do this to keep people from hotlinking directly to the file.

If DTA is initiating a new connection after the link has expired, then that could explain why it's erroring out, especially if the errors occur only on a few websites.

Answer (score 0):

I did experienced this and I was able to resolve the problem by clearing ALL browser history (cache, downloadthemall history, etc). Then restart FF. Worked for me.